# How can I get react-select to integrate properly with react-final-form

Tags: react-select, react-final-form

I'm using `react-final-form` to send along some basic user data. First name, last name, email and a dropdown value with a reason why they're contacting me. I tried the following (the custom input section on `react-final-form`'s docs):

```
<Field name="myField">
  {props => (
    <div>
      <Select
        options={colourOptions}
        className="basic-multi-select"
        classNamePrefix="select"
        onChange={props.input.onChange}
       />
    </div>
  )}
</Field>
```

My guess is maybe there's some collision with the `onChange` prop? Not sure, but the information in the dropdown is not being picked up by `react-final-form` and pass along to the `<form>` on submit.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example on how to use `react-select` with `react-final-form`: https://codesandbox.io/s/40mr0v2r87.

You should add an adapter:

```
const ReactSelectAdapter = ({ input, ...rest }) => (
  <Select {...input} {...rest} />
)
```

And then you can use it as a component:

```
<Field
  name="state"
  component={ReactSelectAdapter}
  options={states}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here my approach. I decided problem with initial values and value which will sent to server. Just like:

> {selectFieldId: "value"}

```
import React from "react";
import { FieldRenderProps } from "react-final-form";
import Select, { ValueType } from "react-select";

type Option = {
    label: string;
    value: string;
};

export const CustomSelect = ({ input, options, ...rest }: FieldRenderProps<string, HTMLElement>) => {

    const handleChange = (option: ValueType<Option, false>) => {
        input.onChange(option?.value);
    };

    return (
            <Select
                {...input}
                {...rest}
                onChange={handleChange}
                options={options}
                value={options ? options.find((option: Option) => option.value === input.value) : ""}
            />
    );
};

export default CustomSelect;
```

Answer (score 0):

in a simple way I have done it like this:

```
 const locationOptions = [
        { value: 1, label: "ADEN" },
        { value: 2, label: "MUKALLA" },
        { value: 3, label: "TAIZ" },
      ];
<Field name="location_id">
              {({ input }) => (
                <Select
                  options={locationOptions}
                  placeholder="Select Location"
                  {...input}
                />
              )}
</Field>
```

the on submit method:

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };
```